# How to delete multiple files on azure blob storage through rest api batch delete

Tags: node.js, azure, rest, request, azure-blob-storage

I was trying to delete the multiple files from the container using the API provided by azure name as blob batch. So i followed the same instruction explained in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-batch)

I am getting the following body in response

```
'--batchresponse_ffab056e-336a-49e9-a878-371bd69b15f6
Content-Type: application/http

HTTP/1.1 400 One of the request inputs is not valid.
x-ms-error-code: InvalidInput
x-ms-request-id: <RequestId>
x-ms-version: 2020-04-08
Content-Length: 221
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidInput</Code><Message>One of the request inputs is not valid.
RequestId: <RequestId>
Time:2021-11-23T13:01:31.5627264Z</Message></Error>
--batchresponse_ffab056e-336a-49e9-a878-371bd69b15f6--'
```

This was my request options and subrequest in batch

```
const boundary = "batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525";
const separation = "--"+boundary + "\n";
const ending = "--" + boundary + "--";
const fileList = ['sample1.json','sample2.json']
    const subRequest = `--batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525\r
Content-Type: application/http\r
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r
\r
DELETE /${azureDirectoryName}/${fileList[0].fileName} HTTP/1.1\r
Host: https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net\r
x-ms-date: ${strTime}\r
Authorization: Bearer ${authToken}\r
Content-Length: 0\r
--batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525--\r`

  const requestObj = {
    'Host': '<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net',
    url: 'https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=batch',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=' + boundary,
      "x-ms-date": new Date(),
      "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
      "Content-Length": subRequest.length,
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken
    },
    body: subRequest
  }
request(requestObj, (err, resp) => {
//internal logic
    })
```

RequestObj JSON

```
'{"url":"https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=batch","method":"POST","headers":{"Content-Type":"multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525","x-ms-date":"Wed, 24 Nov 2021 04:45:21 GMT","x-ms-version":"2018-11-09","Content-Length":2166,"Authorization":"Bearer <authtoken>"},"body":"--batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525\r\nContent-Type: application/http\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\nDELETE /containerName/test.json HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: https://<accountName>.blob.core.windows.net\r\nx-ms-date: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 04:45:21 GMT\r\nAuthorization: Bearer <authToken>\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n--batch_357de4f7-6d0b-4e02-8cd2-6361411a9525--\r"}
```

Comment: For starters, your request is missing authorization header.

Comment: Hi, Gaurav i added the auth to the requestObj now i am getting the following error One of the request inputs is not valid.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of your `requestObj`.

Comment: changes are made @GauravMantri

Comment: I still do not see the output of your requestObj. Basically I want to see what exactly is sent to the storage service. Please obfuscate account name and the bearer token before sharing. Thanks.

Comment: As i can't pass the requestObj could you share one batch delete working example. That might help me

Comment: Just do `console.log(requestObj)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(requestObj))` and share that output.

Comment: I have made the changes @GauravMantri